# Closed under vector multiplication (Sub-algebra)

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm working on a problem in which I had to determine if the set is a subspace and whether it is a sub-algebra. I was able to easily prove subset but I'm not sure how to prove the sub-algebra which requires the set to be closed under vector multiplication. Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

note: This is a homework problem so I am not posting the exact question. I can post it if it is necessary to understanding but would rather not.

edited to add set:
$$S=\{\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \\ \end{bmatrix} |a+c=b+d\}$$

Comment: What is that set?

Comment: In general you need to prove that the product of any two elements in the set is again in the set. It's impossible to say more without any details about the set.

Comment: @user251257 I have added the set but please only provide direction not a full answer.

Comment: @arkeet edited to add set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: We have 
$$\begin{bmatrix} a_1 & b_1 \\ c_1 & d_1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a_2 & b_2 \\ c_2 & d_2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} a_1a_2 + b_1c_2 & a_1b_2 + b_1d_2 \\ c_1a_2 + d_1c_2 & c_1b_2 + d_1d_2 \end{bmatrix},$$

where the first two matrices are in $S$.

Now, if you can show that $(a_1a_2 + b_1c_2) + (c_1a_2 + d_1c_2) = (a_1b_2 + b_1d_2) + (c_1b_2 + d_1d_2)$, what can you conclude?

Comment: What you have written is exactly what I have, so at least I was on the right track.  Can you make the conclusion of closure straight from there or does the equation require more manipulation?

Comment: If you can establish that the equation holds, then you can conclude that the product of the two matrices is in $S$, based on how $S$ is defined. Which is just to say that $S$ is closed.

Comment: I have gotten the equation to $$a_2(a_1 + c_1) + c_2(b_1+d_1)= b_2(a_1+c_1) + d_2(b_1+d_1)$$ Does this indeed show the equation holds? (I feel like it does but cant put into words why...).

Comment: You need to _prove_ that the equation I wrote holds, not operate on the thing I wrote. Just start with the left-hand side and transform it into the right-hand side. You'll have to use the fact that the first two matrices are in $S$, i.e. $a_1 + c_1 = b_1 + d_1$...

Comment: Wow, I should know that...guess its about time for bed :). Thank you for all of your help!